# Changing projection and doing intersection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have some road network data from OSM in EPSG:4326, a polygon representing the boundary of some city in EPSG:4326 that is out of date, and an up to date version of that polygon that is *not* in EPSG:4326. When I check the properties, it says the CRS is the following:

Generated CRS (+proj=lcc +lat_1=44.33333333333334 +lat_2=46 +lat_0=43.66666666666666 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=ft +no_defs)

Now what I want to do is to filter the roads for only those within the city limits then create nodes at the endpoints of the streets. I am using QGIS 2.18.26.

Using the out of date boundary data in EPSG:4326, I can use the Intersection tool to get the streets in the city limits, then use the v.to.points tool in the Processing toolbox to get the endpoints of the streets:

[image: old-city-limits-nodes-success]

Using the new city boundary data, I changed the projection to EPSG:4326 using Save As... Then used the Intersection tool in the same way, which worked fine. But then when I use the v.to.points tool, there is no output:

[image: new-city-limits-nodes-failure]

I assume this has something to do with how I changed the projection, but I'm very new to this stuff so I'm not sure where to go next.

*UPDATE*

I was asked to paste the output of the *Log* tab for the v.to.points tool. The process just runs and then closes so I can't really look at the output. According to [this documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/processing/log.html), I should be able to see the log output at Processing -> History, but there is no log info there, just the "Algorithm" directory that logs the function call.

That being said, I tried going to the *Log* tab and copying the text in there while the process was running. So I may not have all the output, but I see some error messages, so hopefully it is enough for someone else to see what is going wrong:

```
Algorithm v.to.points - Create points along input lines starting...
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1 input="/tmp/processing675fd71b428d47058b057854bf85d1c7" layer=1544809798.2236 output=tmp15448097982637 --overwrite -o
g.region n=45.3300102346 s=45.2834281428 e=-122.925625688 w=-122.98844688 res=100
v.to.points input="tmp15448097982637" dmax="100" use=node output="output5d61527a7ac04a79884d43ae47610b99" --overwrite
v.out.ogr -s -e input=output5d61527a7ac04a79884d43ae47610b99 type=auto output="/tmp/processing675fd71b428d47058b057854bf85d1c7/08803dbec4b44cc99b453612ce41e56f" format=ESRI_Shapefile output_layer=output --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS... 
Executing '/home/mikey/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ... 
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default 
Projection information updated 
Over-riding projection check 
Check if OGR layer contains polygons... 0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Importing 1459 features (OGR layer )... 0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Building topology for vector map ... 
Registering primitives... 

1471 primitives registered 
5379 vertices registered 
Building areas... 0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100 
0 areas built 
0 isles built 
Attaching islands... 
Attaching centroids... 1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100 
Number of nodes: 1150 
Number of primitives: 1471 
Number of points: 0 
Number of lines: 1471 
Number of boundaries: 0 
Number of centroids: 0 
Number of areas: 0 
Number of isles: 0 
DBMI-SQLite driver error: 
Unable to scan date: 

DBMI-SQLite driver error: 
Unable to scan date: 

WARNING: Unable to fetch data from table 
ERROR: Unable to copy table 
WARNING: Table linked to vector map does not exist 
ERROR: Vector map not found 
Execution of '/home/mikey/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' finished. 
Cleaning up temporary files... 
Starting GRASS GIS... 
Executing '/home/mikey/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ... 
ERROR: Vector map not found
```

Comment: Hi @Mikey. Can you copy the output from the _Log_ tab of the `v.to.points` tool in the question?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I've added some of the log output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay found a solution! It looks like someone had a similar problem [in this ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2834#comment:9). They had some Date attribute that had some problems (hence the "Unable to scan date" error I had). I didn't actually need those date column(s) that were just filled with Nulls anyway, so I just removed those attributes, and things seem to be working smoothly! :)